# SQL: How to produce next date given month and day

Tags: sql

In my table I have a Month(tinyint) and a Day(tinyint) field.  I would like to have a function that takes this month and day and produces a datetime for the next date(including year) given this month and day.

So if I had Month = 9, Day = 7 it would produce 9/7/2009. 
If I had Month 1, Day 1 it would produce 1/1/2010.

Comment: how do you know what year to use? Are you just assuming it will always be based off the current date?  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: It's based off of today. So lets say today is 6/23/2009.  The date in the table is month=6, day = 22.  Then I want it to return 6/22/2010 because that is the next date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would work. It's variation on your method, but it doesn't use the MM/DD/YYYY literal format, and it won't blowup against bad input (for better or for worse).

```
declare @month tinyint
declare @day tinyint
set @month = 9
set @day = 1

declare @date datetime

-- this could be inlined if desired
set @date = convert(char(4),year(getdate()))+'0101'
set @date = dateadd(month,@month-1,@date)
set @date = dateadd(day,@day-1,@date)

if @date <= getdate()-1
  set @date = dateadd(year,1,@date)

select @date
```

Alternatively, to create a string in YYYYMMDD format:

```
set @date = 
  right('0000'+convert(char(4),year(getdate())),4)
+ right('00'+convert(char(2),@month),2)
+ right('00'+convert(char(2),@day),2)
```

Another method, which avoids literals all together:

```
declare @month tinyint
declare @day tinyint
set @month = 6
set @day = 24

declare @date datetime
declare @today datetime

-- get todays date, stripping out the hours and minutes
-- and save the value for later
set @date = floor(convert(float,getdate()))
set @today = @date

-- add the appropriate number of months and days
set @date = dateadd(month,@month-month(@date),@date)
set @date = dateadd(day,@day-day(@date),@date)

-- increment year by 1 if necessary
if @date < @today set @date = dateadd(year,1,@date)

select @date
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sql example so far.  I don't really like it though...

```
DECLARE @month tinyint,
    @day tinyint,
    @date datetime

SET @month = 1
SET @day = 1

-- SET DATE TO DATE WITH CURRENT YEAR
SET @date = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar,@month) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar,@day) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(GETDATE())))


-- IF DATE IS BEFORE TODAY, ADD ANOTHER YEAR
IF (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), @date) < 0)
BEGIN
    SET @date = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @date)
END

SELECT @date
```

Comment: Don't use MM/DD/YYYY format for date literals. Use YYYYMMDD instead. It will avoid localization issues, and it sorts properly.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't see a problem with your method. Do you dislike the conversion from a literal?

Comment: It seems like something that there should be some easy solution to.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to format it this way?  I'm having troubles turning Month=1 into a string of "01".

Comment: I added another method that doesn't require date literals at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with PostgreSQL

```
your_date_calculated = Year * 10000 + Month * 100 + Day
```

gives you a date like 20090623.

```
select cast( cast( your_date_calculated as varchar )  as date ) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. The core of it is just two lines, using the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function, and it doesn't require any conversion to/from strings, floats or anything else:

```
DECLARE @Month TINYINT
DECLARE @Day TINYINT

SET @Month = 9
SET @Day = 7

DECLARE @Result DATETIME

SET @Result =
    DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1900) * 12) + @Month - 1, @Day - 1)
IF (@Result < GETDATE())
    SET @Result = DATEADD(year, 1, @Result)

SELECT @Result
```

Comment: Nice. How about an in-line version to avoid the function call overhead?  eg, SELECT DATEADD(year,<expression here>,DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1900) * 12) + MonthField - 1, DayField - 1)) as NewDate FROM ....